# Plot issue (actual and fitted values) in factorAnalytics package in R

Tags: r, finance

I am just moving my first steps with the factorAnalytics package. I am running factorAnalytics v.2.0.30 (the latest version AFAIK) in R 3.3.1 (64bit) with RStudio in Windows.

I am running this code (taken from the help of plot.tsfm):

```
library(factorAnalytics)
data(managers)
fit.macro <- fitTsfm(asset.names=colnames(managers[,(1:6)]),
                     factor.names=colnames(managers[,(7:9)]),
                     rf.name="US.3m.TR", data=managers)

range(index(managers))

plot(fit.macro, plot.single=TRUE, asset.name="HAM1", which=1)
```

The plot is supposed to show the actual and fitted value of HAM1 over the period 1996-2006, but all I have is this:

[Actual and Fitted:HAM1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Gmj.jpg)

that is, the graph only shows actual values for 1996 and no fitted values at all. I tried the same instructions with other time series included in the same database and I always get the same issue. I tried to run the same code from the Rgui (to check if it was a RStudio issue) but it did not help.

I would appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v2.0.33 is the latest version of factorAnalytics. I have that version on my machine and I am not able to reproduce your issue while running your code. Below attached is the plot I got after running the same code.

[image: Actual vs Fitted: HAM1]

Can you try installing the most recent version of the package and see if the problem is reproducible.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13059581)

Comment: @konkked That link is an image ... please revoke that flag

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer should have been displayed as an image, and I didn't flag this item when I reviewed it, just commented and left as OK

Comment: @Avinash          Thank you for answering. 
My bad. I do have factorAnalytics 2.033 installed (and not 2.030 as I erroneously indicated) and of course I still have exactly the same issue. However since the code works on your machine, it must be a problem with my setup. Would you mind to tell me what operating system you are using? (I am on Windows 8.1 64bits)

Comment: @FrankC I use Windows 10, 64 bit with R studio v3.3.1